# How to force vim to edit the previous file (CTRL-^)

Tags: vim

I frequently use [CTRL-6](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#CTRL-%5E) to jump to the previously edited file in vim.

When I use it in a file that I have modified, but not saved, vim will give me the error

`No write since last change (use ! to override)`

Is the a way to add `!` to my hotkey in those cases? Or is `:e! #` my only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `nnoremap <C-^> :e! #<CR>` to your `.vimrc` file to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> (**unfavorable**).

However, if you do so switching to the previous file will result in losing unsaved changes made to the recent file. Therefore I recommend one of the following alternatives:

- Add `set hidden` to your `.vimrc` file to not unload a buffer if it gets abandoned, see VIM's online help `:help hidden` (**preferred solution**).
- Enable autowrite by adding `set autowrite` to your `.vimrc` (**feasible alternative**).

Comment: Your last two recommendations are good (in particular, `set hidden` is what I'd recommend here.) Your first one is not. May I suggest you rephrase your answer to focus on `set hidden` first, `set autowrite` second (not as good, since you may have planned to discard the changes on that buffer.) And I'd suggest just dropping the `:e!` one, or just mention it with a warning that it'll lose data most probably.

Comment: @filbranden I entirely agree, but since it was explicitly asked how to remap Ctrl+^  the first paragraph contains the (only) correct answer. Instead of rephrasing my answer, I added bold text to indicate which solution should be preferred. Together with your comment this should be sufficient. If you disagree, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I take it there is no way to apply the "force" mechanism of ! to, say, the most recent hotkey command entered? The same way I would do with `sudo !!`in bash?

Comment: The first (marked unfavorable) solution suppress the warning for the Ctrl+^ hotkey. Of course you could remap other keys in a similar way to suppress other warnings, too. But bear in mind that those warnings are there for a reason, as pointed out by @filbranden.